# How to collect all responses under one column in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a form that asks for the team leader name 5 times for 5 departments I need to make an array to collect all the answers under one column.

I tried this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Team Leader#",IF(LEN(A:A)=0,IFERROR(1/0),IFS(AND(ISBLANK(B:B),ISBLANK(C:C),ISBLANK(D:D),ISBLANK(E:E)),F:F,
AND(ISBLANK(F:F),ISBLANK(C:C),ISBLANK(D:D),ISBLANK(E:E)),B:B,
AND(ISBLANK(B:B),ISBLANK(F:F),ISBLANK(D:D),ISBLANK(E:E)),C:C,
AND(ISBLANK(F:F),ISBLANK(C:C),ISBLANK(B:B),ISBLANK(E:E)),D:D,
AND(ISBLANK(F:F),ISBLANK(C:C),ISBLANK(B:B),ISBLANK(D:D)),E:E))))
```

But it returns Error no match

Here is a sample of the [Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SksZv0h82j5oEZBj2AN5anDFr80AYNR5ettSwkpUKys/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> collect all responses under one column in google sheets

```
={"Team Leader#"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F),,999^99))))}
```

[image: 0]